# Create slideshow-type video using Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video, slideshow

OK, here's what I'm trying to do :

- Get some images
- Put one after the other (using some fixed intervals)
- Export the result as a video (the format does not matter)

Any ideas on how I would go about it? Any reference to point me to would be more than welcome...

Comment: Apple's developer site has tons of sample code and docs that will help you out. My suggestion is to separate your problems. First, getting images. Write that part of the app. If you have a specific problem, as k about it here. When that is done move on to the ordering.